# NetworkX: Subgraph matching

Tags: python, graph, networkx

Trying to match a Query subgraph to a Target graph, where:

Query:

[image]

and Target:

[image]

As I understand matching in this case should return tuples of matching nodes:

```
(1,1)
(2,2)
(3,3)
```

where first number is a node in Query and second is node in Target

Yet with the following code I get another result:

```
import networkx as nx
import networkx.algorithms.isomorphism as iso

# Target graph
target = nx.Graph()
target.add_edge(1, 2)
target.add_edge(1, 3)
target.add_edge(1, 5)
target.add_edge(2, 3)
target.add_edge(3, 4)
target.add_edge(4, 5)

# Add attributes to target nodes
target.nodes[1]['cat'] = 1
target.nodes[2]['cat'] = 2
target.nodes[3]['cat'] = 3
target.nodes[4]['cat'] = 4
target.nodes[5]['cat'] = 5

# Query graph
query = nx.Graph()
query.add_edge(1, 2)
query.add_edge(1, 3)
query.add_edge(2, 3)

# Add attributes to query graph
query.nodes[1]['cat'] = 1
query.nodes[2]['cat'] = 2
query.nodes[3]['cat'] = 3

# GraphMatcher is supposed to call this function when matching nodes
def node_match(q_node_dict, t_node_dict): # This is never called!
    #print("q_node_dict: {} t_node_dict: {}".format(q_node_dict, t_node_dict))
    return q_node_dict['cat'] == t_node_dict['cat']

# Matcher
GM = iso.GraphMatcher(query, target, node_match=node_match)

# This should print matching nodes?
for x in GM.candidate_pairs_iter():
    print(x)

# What this should print?
for x in GM.subgraph_isomorphisms_iter():
    print(x)
```

Instead code in `GM.candidate_pairs_iter()` returns:

```
(1,1)
(2,1)
(3,1)
```

As if all nodes in Query match to a single node '1' in the Target. Why?

Iterator `GM.subgraph_isomorphisms_iter()` is empty. What should it iterate?

In hope to facilitate subgraph matching I have added attributes to Query and Target. Nodes 1,2,3 in Query and Target have the same values and should match, but it looks like they don't.

According to [NetworkX documentation](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.isomorphism.GraphMatcher.__init__.html#networkx.algorithms.isomorphism.GraphMatcher.__init__) `node_match` parameter of `GraphMatcher` constructor  is a "callable function that returns True iff node n1 in G1 and n2 in G2 should be considered equal during the isomorphism test. The function will be called like:

`node_match(G1.nodes[n1], G2.nodes[n2])` "

and this function is never called in my case!

What am I missing? Thanks!